# Почему не скроллится плавно мобильная верстка?

Tags: css, ios, вёрстка, google-chrome, прокрутка

По какой причине может быть очень резкий скролл сайта в мобильном браузере chrome ios? Хотелось бы видеть его плавным с небольшой задержкой.

Answer (score 1):

У вас программный скролл или скролл, который совершает непосредственно пользователь? Если программный, то просто ставьте задержку скроллинга, например так:

```
destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({scrollTop: destination}, 1100);
```

Comment: извините, а что значит программный?) я захожу на сайт как пользователь и скроллю его, а он скроллится резко, останавливается резко и не ездит)

Comment: Адрес сайта дайте, я у себя проверю. Может у вас просто какие-то глюки... так бывает иногда

Comment: глюка нет, проверено посещением других сайтов, а сам сайт на локалке..

Comment: тогда я врядли чем могу помочь...